# How to create static pattern texture?

Tags: texturing

Is there a node setup to create a texture like that which can be seen on the clothes in the show Chowder?

(I tried really really hard to get a gif small enough to upload to blender stack exchange but in the end I sadly could not so please take this stillframe and if you don't understand what the texture looks like in motion maybe just look at a youtube video or something idk)[image]

Ideally I would like to choose an image as the static pattern and have the textured object move across it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you just need  to use a Texture Coordinate and plug in the Window dot into the texture.

Comment: @Vagabonk I actually love you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered in the commentary while I was writing this.. but here goes. anyway:

The 'Window' texture coordinate runs 0-1, left-to-right, and bottom-to-top, of the camera's view.

When corrected for the camera's aspect ratio, it will result in your texture mapped, undistorted, across the rendered rectangle:

[image]

Above, the Output Properties, X and Y resolutions, have been copied as drivers, and pasted into the value fields, so the texture stays in proportion when the aspect ratio is changed, but you probably don't need to do that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed followup @Robin Betts